# ticks for matplotlib twinx axes not current

Tags: python, matplotlib, twinx

Hey I have issue with the matplotlib twinx axes, I have 2 plot with the same X ticks,
But when I set them both in the same plot with twinx I get wrong plot.

- The first plot data:

  ```
  Potential_Date_month
  1     0.033616
  2     0.033256
  3     0.026578
  4     0.029624
  5     0.026549
  6     0.029654
  7     0.031489
  8     0.025707
  9     0.030870
  10    0.023068
  11    0.042049
  12    0.056363
  Name: target, dtype: int64
  ```

and plot looks:

[image]

- The secand plot data:

  ````
  Potential_Date_month
  1      7318
  2      6886
  3     18737
  4     11342
  5     19624
  6     22324
  7     18451
  8     15988
  9      5928
  10     5462
  11    10250
  12     5571
  Name: target, dtype: int64```
  ````

[image]

But when I use the next code, something get wrong:

```
    fig,ax1 = plt.subplots()
    ax2 = ax1.twinx()

    series1.plot(ax = ax1,color = 'blue')
    series2.plot.bar(ax = ax2, color = 'green', alpha = 0.5)

    plt.show()
```

plot:

[image: s]

you can see the line plot isn't staring from one ticks, it start with 2.
I'm not sure what cause this issue,

Thank you.

Comment: Pandas' bar plots are automatically made "categorical", setting the first bar at internal position "0", the second at "1", ... and then labeling the bars with the values from the index. The lineplot, however, will use the numeric values.  Often a simple trick is to make the index column categorical.

Comment: You can use `ax1.plot(range(len(series1)), series1, color='blue')` to create the lineplot via matplotlib, using the same x-positions as the bar plot.